# Compute the height of the fixed header and add it as top margin to the element below it

Tags: javascript, html

The page does not have jquery so this needs to be done by vanilla JS only.

The header is fixed to the top i.e `position:fixed;` and so is taken away from the regular flow and the banner below takes it place causing an overlap.

```
<header class="site-header fixed-top">
    fixed top header
</header>
<section class="banner">
    banner
</section>
```

To remedy this, I want to give the `.banner` section a top margin equaling the height of `.site-header`.

I have got the height by using the JS below,

```
var headerHeight = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName("site-header")[0]).height;
```

But having trouble finding the right way to target the next element `.banner`

By traversing the DOM tree in the console I found that the following leads to it but it seems wrong and complicated.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("site-header")[0].nextSibling.nextElementSibling.style.marginTop = headerHeight;
```

Is there a better and easier way to do it?

Comment: why cant you getElementByClassName on banner?

Comment: _Offtopic_: I would rather use native `position: sticky` instead of JavaScript solution.

Comment: @VladimirM the class name .banner might change and I want this to be a general purpose solution.

Comment: @Jax-p curious to know why?

Comment: @VinithAlmeida `sticky` acts like a `fixed`  when it is sticked but acts like a static element while it is not. It means you don't need to `margin-top` anything. It just works in native way. You can see [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) over the internet. In your case `position: sticky; top: 0;` for the header could solve this without JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CSS only solution

Sticky acts like a fixed when it is sticked but acts like a static element while it is not. It means you don't need to margin-top anything. It just works in native way.

```css
.site-header {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.wrap {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <header class="site-header">
      fixed top header
  </header>
  <section class="banner">
      banner
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `offsetHeight` or `clientHeight` for the header height, and use `previousElementSibling` to find the section preceded by the header. Something like:

```js
setTimeout(setSectionMargin, 1000);

function setSectionMargin() {
  const sectionAfterFixedHeader = [...document.querySelectorAll(`.banner`)]
    .filter(b => b.previousElementSibling.classList.contains(`fixed-top`)).pop();

  if (sectionAfterFixedHeader) {
    const header = sectionAfterFixedHeader.previousElementSibling;
    sectionAfterFixedHeader.style.marginTop = `${header.clientHeight}px`;
  }
}
```

```css
.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.site-header {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.3em 0;
}

.banner {
  color: red;
  transition: all 1s 0s;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header fixed-top">
  fixed top header
</header>
<section class="banner">
  banner 1
</section>
<section class="banner">
  banner 2
</section>
<section class="banner">
  banner 3
</section>
```

Or indeed [jax-p's css `sticky` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69678097/compute-the-height-of-the-fixed-header-and-add-it-as-top-margin-to-the-element-b/69678512#69678512) ([not (completely) supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky) by specific or older browsers)